# Error when running JUnit 5 tests in IntelliJ but not on the command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

The following error is reported when I attempt to run a simple JUnit 5 test in IntelliJ:

```
Feb 08, 2019 3:37:39 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable 
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryFiltersByType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/List; 
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.JUnit4DiscoveryRequestResolver.filterAndConvertToTestClassRequests(JUnit4DiscoveryRequestResolver.java:79)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.JUnit4DiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(JUnit4DiscoveryRequestResolver.java:48)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:64) 
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177) 
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164) 
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120) 
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:49) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V 
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my pom:

```
<properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit.jupiter.version> 
</properties>

</dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> 
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId> 
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version> 
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> 
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId> 
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version> 
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <!-- Only needed to run tests in a version of IntelliJ IDEA that bundles older versions --> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> 
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId> 
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version> 
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> 
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4.0</version> 
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>

<build> 
    <plugins> 
        <!-- JUnit 5 requires Surefire version 2.22.1 or higher --> 
        <plugin> 
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.22.1</version> 
        </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
</build>
```

I am using Intellij v2017.1.2.

When I run the test from the command line there are no errors reported.

I've seen various posts reporting similar problems for different versions of IntelliJ but the suggested solutions don't help.

Comment: You should consider using the [junit-bom](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.2/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-bom) so that the versions of junit-jupiter and junit-platform match.

Answer (score 3):

The [JUnit User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.2/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea) suggests to use 2017.3 or newer.

> IntelliJ IDEA releases prior to IDEA 2017.3 bundle specific versions of JUnit 5. Thus, if you want to use a newer version of JUnit Jupiter, execution of tests within the IDE might fail due to version conflicts.

Comment: Upgrading is not an option at the moment.

Comment: IntelliJ 2017.1.2 bundles JUnit 5.0.0-M4, see [this overview](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea). So if you can't upgrade IntelliJ, then you should downgrade JUnit to this version. Otherwise, you will run into the described version conflicts. (I consider not running tests from within the IDE is not an option)

Comment: Your IDEA version has compilation dependency on the old junit 5. To make tests run with IDEA you have to change junit dependencies to the bundled, you may check what versions are bundled in IDEA_INSTALLATION_HOME/plugins/junit/lib. Also pay attention that junit-platform-commons has to be added:

<dependency>

            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>

            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>

            <version>1.0.0-M4</version>

            <scope>test</scope>

        </dependency>
And maven-surefire-plugin downgraded to 2.19.1